# How to filter Model instances for company in Model Manager Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am building a website which will have many companies and each company will have many users. How do I separate the users by company so that the users of each company are all segregated from each other?

**Example**

Let us say I have a couple models such as `User`, `Company` and `Memo`...

```
class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company)

class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Memo(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField()
    date_time = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Each memo should be separated by company so that no user from  `Company A` can see `Company B`'s memos. My website will have a lot of this type of logic.  The company will be applied to each user should we be applying a filter in each view such as:

```
User.object.filter(company_id='1')
```

Is there a way put this logic in the `Model` or `Model Manager` so that we use [Fat Models and Skinny Views](https://hackerfall.com/story/fat-models--a-django-code-organization-strategy)? Or can we not do this because the user's company is outside the scope of the `Memo` model?

Comment: It would have been helpful if you had done shown some code. But what you are asking seems to me more of a question of modeling. Django querysets are lazy which therefore means that filtering is always efficient. My advice is to avoid filtering from the template. The best place is model managers. Please read more on Database normalization [link](https://gerardnico.com/data/modeling/normalization#targetText=Normalization%20is%20a%20logical%20data,data%20to%20its%20canonical%20form.). Its IMPORTANT TO DESIGN YOUR TABLES WELL

Comment: Updated question to be more specific..

Comment: If possible use model managers to filter things. I don't see logic in your modeling though e.g. there is a `sender` but no `receiver`. Further it is not clear who should see a Memo. Are you sure that a user can belong to multiple companies. I would advice get `two scoops of Django` and take time to read.

Comment: I have a receiver but I removed it to shorten the model for the question (now changed to author to be more readable). The people who should see it should belong to their company. Also, I got the `user` attribute wrong in the `Company` model. It should be a `ForeignKey` pointed to company under the user model. I will update it. Also, I own TSoD so I will read it more.

Comment: I see where you are going. You could do it this way `Memo.objects.filter(author__company=company)`  if you are in the view you could get company as `request.user.company` which translates to `Memo.objects.filter(author__company=request.user.company)` You want to avoid duplicate relations as they could result in the update anomaly Read on database normalization. If you want to define your own user, extend from `AbstractBaseUser` and ensure that your settings file reflect it.

Comment: Is this `Memo.objects.filter(author__company=company)` in a `ModelManager`? I am trying to learn how to structure my Django code *correctly* rather than throwing everything in the view. Also, this is the answer I was looking for. If you add it as answer I will checkmark it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200671/discussion-between-unlockme-and-david-alford).

Comment: @DavidAlford Asking *"Where should all this filtering be done?"* makes your question seem opinionated, while asking *"Is there a way put this logic in the Model"* is a perfectly valid question.  I went ahead and removed the opinionated part for you, since this your question worthy of reopening.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `ForeignKey` and create a `Many-to-one relationships` between company and user.

And to filter users, you should use `Company ForeignKey` in the query.

I have worked on many Django projects and I think this is the way you should go with.

Comment: Where should these queries be done? I assume you mean something like: `user_a = request.user` then `memo.object.filter(sender=user_a)` in the view? Or should I be making queries in model/model-manager?

Comment: Query in view, for eg: `User.objects.filter(company_id=1)`, It will return all the users which are of company id=1.

Comment: Updated question above to be more detailed and less subjective. Also, added question about handling this in views...